# multiple select option only select last last selected php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do multiple select in a drop down using php but when I select two or three elements 
it only shows results for one. . I really do not know here am going wrong . I want when I select those three or 4 items then i get the results then I use them to query a table looping trough
Here is my code

```
<form action ="sendnow.php"  method ="post"  name="contactform"  id ="--contactform" >

     <?php 
     //Get member type      
     $sele_membertype="
    SELECT members.cell, members.rank,company.companyid FROM members
    INNER JOIN company ON company.usercode = members.usercode  
    WHERE members.usercode = '$usercode' && CHAR_LENGTH(members.cell)>10 && members.active ='Yes'
    GROUP BY members.rank ";
$user_coder1 = $con->prepare($sele_membertype);
$user_coder1 ->execute();?>
<!--Linksfield 22:36 22/03/2016 Tuesday : Musa Linksfield -->
<label class="control-label" for="selectError">Select Member type</label>
     <select multiple = "MULTIPLE" size ="6" name ="rank[]" id="rank" >
     <?php              
     while($record = $user_coder1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

         $rank = $record['rank'];
         ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $rank;?>"><?php echo $rank;?></option>
         <?php
     }?>
 </select>
<textarea id="sendlistme" name="sendlistme[]"></textarea>             

     <div class="box box-info">
     <div class="box-header">
     <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
     <h3 class="box-title">Quick Sms</h3>
     <!-- tools box -->
     <div class="pull-right box-tools">
     <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
     </div><!-- /. tools -->
     </div>
     <div class="box-body">

     <div>
     <textarea class="textarea" onkeyup="countChar(this)" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" style="width: 100%; height: 125px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
     </div>
     <h3><div id="charNum" style='color:red'></div></h3>

     </div>
     <div class="box-footer clearfix">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value ="Send" name ="submit">
     </div>
     </div> 
     </div><!-- /.form group -->
</form>
```

my php

```
/*Get user codeends */
$user_coder ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".($_SESSION['username'])."'";
$user_coder1 = $con->prepare($user_coder);
$user_coder1 ->execute();
$row =$user_coder1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$usercode = $row['usercode'];
/*Get user codeends ends*/
$message=(isset($_POST['message']))? trim($_POST['message']): '';
//$rank =(isset($_POST['rank']))? trim($_POST['rank']): '';

// calculate characters in an sms 
$characters = mb_strlen($message);
$messagenum = 1;
//echo "<h1>".$characters."</h1>";
if($characters > 120  && $characters <=240){
    $messagenum = 2;
}

else if($characters > 240  && $characters <=360){
    $messagenum = 3;
}
//echo "<h1>Number of Message:".$messagenum."</h1>";

//End calculations

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($message)){
        echo ("Type some message");
        exit();
    }
    $create_member ="
SELECT company.companyid, users.usercode,company.cell,company.company,company.datejoined,
 users.usercode,users.userid FROM company
 INNER JOIN users ON users.usercode = company.usercode
 WHERE   users.username = '".($_SESSION['username'])."'
";
    $user_coder1 = $con->prepare($create_member);
    $user_coder1 ->execute();
    $row =$user_coder1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $companyid = $row['companyid'];
    $userid =    $row['userid'];

    $user_coder ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".($_SESSION['username'])."'";
    $user_coder1 = $con->prepare($user_coder);
    $user_coder1 ->execute();
    $row =$user_coder1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $usercode = $row['usercode'];
    $sentby =  $row['username'];
    $timesent=date('y-m-d H:i:s');
    ?>
    <?php   
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    foreach($_POST['rank'] AS $finalrank1){  // this is my loop from the dropdown menu 
        $finalrank = $finalrank1;
        echo $finalrank;
        $get_taget="
SELECT members.surname ,members.usercode,members.cell, members.rank,company.company, company.companyid FROM members
INNER JOIN company ON company.companyid = members.companyid  
WHERE members.rank = '$finalrank' && members.usercode='$usercode'  && members.active='Yes' && CHAR_LENGTH(members.cell)=11
GROUP BY members.cell ORDER BY members.cell";
        $targe1 = $con->prepare($get_taget);
        $targe1 ->execute();
        $mycountsmsreal = $targe1->rowCount();

        //$mycountsms = $mycountsmsreal * $messagenum;
        //ends
        $comma =",";
        while($record = $targe1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            //$cell = $record['cell'] ;
            $company = $record['company'];
            $surname = $record['surname'];
            $final_cell .= $record['cell'].',';
        }
        //echo
        $final_cell= substr($final_cell,0,-1);
        //count sms and management call 
        include_once("countSms.php");
        /// ends here 
        // call the sms plugin
        include_once("gamam.php");
        // end button 
        echo  $final_cell ;
    }
}

/// Update sms 

?>
```

Comment: Since you're using a prepared statement, why aren't you using a parameter instead of substituting the `$finalrank` variable into the SQL?

Comment: I can't see a reason why you're only getting one of the ranks. However, you should initialize `$final_cell` to an empty string before the `while` loop, otherwise you'll concatenate the results for each rank.

Comment: Your contribution is appreciated but now I really do not know why I do not get the intended results

Comment: Check the Network tab of the browser console, make sure it's sending all the selections. You should see something like `rank[]=xxx&rank[]=yyy`

Comment: Thanks I will do that